# Android - Can I add libs , apk or code into expansion files? (obb)

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle, apk-expansion-files

My APK code is 10 MB, resources about another 10MB.  However I need to use two big libs that increases the app size to over 130 MB.

My first idea was to use expansion files but documentation is pretty ambiguous and always talks about "recommendations" and not actual possibilities.

So my question is, can I download the libs (.jar), (.aar) as expansion files?  Is it prohibited or it is only a recommendation to not do so (for security reasons of malicious software altering the code)

Right now, I cannot use app bundles because the tool that adds a RASP layer to app apparently cannot process aabs.